# How do I make <li> with block elements sit beside each other?

Tags: html, css

I have a mockup layout for something [here](http://www.mylittlepwnage.com/misc/forms-editor.html). Essentially there are sections, columns and fields, which are all written as a combination of `<ul>` and `<li>` elements. This is done specifically for later parsing.

A snippet of the HTML:

```
<li class="layout"><span class="type">[Column] </span>
    <ul class="layout-children">
        <li class="field"><span class="type">[Text] </span>A field</li>
        <li class="field"><span class="type">[Text] </span>Another field</li>
        <li class="field"><span class="type">[Text] </span>Yet another field</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="layout"><span class="type">[Column] </span>
    <ul class="layout-children">
        <li class="field"><span class="type">[Text] </span>More fields</li>
        <li class="field"><span class="type">[Text] </span>And one more field</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

If you go to the [linked content](http://www.mylittlepwnage.com/misc/forms-editor.html) you'll note that those columns sit vertically.
I want the columns to sit beside each other, but I am not sure how to go about it.

It would be preferable if the HTML didn't change, just the CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just added this to your css:

```
ul .section-children li.layout {
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how well supported inline-block is nowadays.

Comment: inline-block is definitely the way to go, if it works on the systems you're targeting.

Comment: inline-block is certainly supported by both IE 6 and 7... on inline elements.

Comment: It's not, however, supported by Firefox < 3. Which is why my answer included -moz-inline-box.

Answer (score 8):

```
display: -moz-inline-box;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
```

Comment: @CharlesPrakashDasari, older versions of IE (6 and 7) don't support `inline-block` on elements which default to `block`. But `inline` plus IE's proprietary `hasLayout` state is identical to `inline-block`. The `*` prefix targets a CSS parsing bug in these older IE versions, isolating those styles. `zoom: 1` triggers `hasLayout` without any side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

In your `<UL>` tag use the css attribute "list-style:none;" and in the `<li>` tag use the css attribute "display:inline;" you'll have to play around with the padding and margin to make it look good, but those two attributes will get you on your way. For a better example see my Non-Profit website: [Technically Learning](http://technicallylearning.org)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
.layout { float: left; width: 50%; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; /* background: transparent */ }
* html .layout { display: inline } /* IE margin hack */
.field { clear: both }
```

Comment: there are ways to deal with this without the hack, so I would not suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

yeah using `display:block` it would be impossible to make them sit beside each other unless if you'd try to specify a width for each of them
but if that's the case just use `display:inline`

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative to using inline elements since IE has had a history of padding problems with inline:

```
.layout-children:after
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.layout-children .field
{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: IE also has a history of problems with :after pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using `inline` or `inline-block` is going to be nothing but trouble. It's a much better idea to use floats as @Dmitry Z has suggested (but without the margin hack, which isn't necessary).

Answer (score 0):

A simple float: left will work (with a minor adjustment for the width)

```
li {
    margin: .5em 1em;
    padding: .1em;

    font-family: sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px #666 solid;
    float: left;
}
#layout-section {
    width: 85%;
}
```